# Reuse session and create URL for new Custom page

Tags: java, sdk, microstrategy

Can someone suggest how can I re-use the existing session for the Web URL (created MSTR Web page) refresh based on the button click (reload the same page)?

Session is created based on the user login when the link is clicked for the user to login.

```
http://localhost/microstategy/asp/main.aspx?Pg=custompage

Currently with every refresh from button click new user connection is created. I would like to re-use the same session instead if creating new ones.


session1.setServerName("WebServer1");}
session1.setServerPort(34952);
 session1.setAuthMode(EnumDSSXMLAuthModes.DssXmlAuthStandard); session1.setProjectName("Project Name");
factory.getClusterAdmin().setKeepAlive(true);
sessionState1=session1.saveState(0);​
```